# Format number to 2 decimal places

Tags: mysql, formatting, decimal

I would like to know how can I output a number with 2 decimal places, without rounding the original number.

For example:

```
2229,999 -> 2229,99
```

I already tried:

```
FORMAT(2229.999, 2)
CONVERT(2229.999, DECIMAL(4,2))
```

Comment: it looks like you are trying to use commands to truncate. Why not just use the built in funcationality?

Comment: Don't you need the decimal to be `DECIMAL(6,2))`. 6- Precision ( number of total digits) and 2 is the number of digits after decimal ?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You want to use the `TRUNCATE` command.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_truncate

Comment: Truncate always "rounds" down.  1.999 truncated to 2 DP would be 1.99 where 2.00 would mathematically be more correct.  If that's not a problem then truncate's fine but you should be aware of it.

Comment: I agree to GordonM and TRUNCATE should be used with causion, especially with floating point numbers!

Answer (score 427):

When formatting number to 2 decimal places you have two options `TRUNCATE` and `ROUND`. You are looking for `TRUNCATE` function.

Examples:

**Without rounding:**

```
TRUNCATE(0.166, 2)
-- will be evaluated to 0.16

TRUNCATE(0.164, 2)
-- will be evaluated to 0.16
```

docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_truncate

**With rounding:**

```
ROUND(0.166, 2)
-- will be evaluated to 0.17

ROUND(0.164, 2)
-- will be evaluated to 0.16
```

docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round

Comment: you should use `truncate` to format numbers when you want truncated numbers. she made it quite clear in the question that this is what she wanted to do. there are many ways of rounding (floor, ceiling, away-from-zero, toward-zero, half-up, half-down, half-even). they are appropriate in different contexts.

Comment: yeah of course, but as I can see many people find that my answer was helpful or maybe they found this question when they were looking for ROUND command. I will leave it as it is.

Comment: _"you shouldn't use TRUNCATE to format numbers because you will simply lose truncated digits"_ => Well, that's the point of truncature... I don't see how we should get 0.17 with Math. Your answer is perfect for programming examples but it is not very thorough.

Comment: As I said before. I KNOW that it is not a correct answer for this question but people tend to like it :) Maybe because of the question title which could be the search result for someone who is looking for the `ROUND` function.

Comment: Then you should fix it. I will still get useful for everyone, _and_ it will be 100% correct. Win-win :)

Comment: is this rounding `ROUND` safe to use with money values?

Comment: Truncate was working fine for me until I saw this issue.
When I truncate 00.01 then it is giving me 00.01 which is correct. 
But when I do :-
Actual amount: 20574.01
After Truncate: 20574.00
Why so?

Comment: Given 5 or 5.5 this does not "*output a number with 2 decimal places*" which is what the question asks.

Comment: I do approve the fact you have put in ROUND also. It is the correct way to do it so it should be mentioned!

Answer (score 24):

How about 
`CAST(2229.999 AS DECIMAL(6,2))`
to get a decimal with 2 decimal places

Comment: I think you mean cast(2229.999 as decimal(4,2))

Comment: @Pacerier - Both work technically.  However the format for convert is convert(2229.999, decimal(4,2)) with a comma, so you're probably right in that that was what he was going for.

Comment: @UncleIroh, Ah yes, my typo above. I was talking about `convert(2229.999, decimal(4,2))`.

Comment: CAST(2229.999 AS DECIMAL(4,2)) will give you 99.99. DECIMAL is the maximum number of digits **including** the 2 to the left of the decimal place. CAST(2229.99 AS DECIMAL(6,2)) will give you 2230.00

Answer (score 16):

Just use

```
format(number, qtyDecimals)
sample: format(1000, 2)
result 1000.00
```

Comment: Depending on your locale `SELECT FORMAT(100000, 2);` outputs: `100,000.00`.  I'm pretty sure this will mess up an application that's expecting a number.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I used this is as an example:

```
CAST(vAvgMaterialUnitCost.`avgUnitCost` AS DECIMAL(11,2)) * woMaterials.`qtyUsed` AS materialCost
```

Answer (score 1):

Show as decimal
Select ifnull(format(100.00, 1, 'en_US'), 0)
100.0

Show as Percentage
Select concat(ifnull(format(100.00, 0, 'en_US'), 0), '%')
100%