# MySQL Percentage of 2 columns not working =NULL

Tags: mysql, sql, multiple-columns, percentage

I have the following statement in MYSQL:

```
SELECT Site, Areateam, 
SUM( IF( year = '15-16', 1, 0 ) ) "Y2", 
SUM( IF( year = '14-15', 1, 0 ) ) "Y1",
SUM('Y2') / SUM('Y1')* 100 AS Diff
FROM CD2015_EmailIncidents
WHERE Areateam = 'Greater Manchester'
GROUP BY Site
```

which returns the following results:

```
**Site           |Areateam             |Y2  |Y1  |Diff**

Acute Trust      |Greater Manchester   |0   |1   |NULL

Care Home        |Greater Manchester   |3   |22  |NULL

CD Store Room    |Greater Manchester   |7   |4   |NULL

College Greater  |Greater Manchester   |0   |1   |NULL
```

I cant seem to the correct syntax to show the percentage difference between Y2 and Y1 as it keeps displaying NULL

Many thanks
Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are doing arithmetic on string values:

```
SUM('Y2') / SUM('Y1')* 100 AS Diff
```

MySQL does silent conversion, so it converts the values to numbers.  There are no leading digits, so they are converted to 0.

MySQL then returns `NULL` for `0/0`.

Juergen has the right solution for this.  Your overall query can be expressed as:

```
SELECT Site, Areateam, 
       SUM(year = '15-16') as Y2, 
       SUM(year = '14-15') as Y1,
       100 * SUM(year = '15-16') / SUM(year = '14-15') AS Diff
FROM CD2015_EmailIncidents
WHERE Areateam = 'Greater Manchester'
GROUP BY Site;
```

Comment: Its it possible to adjust the 'diff' decimal point? so it shows 0% or 12% etc...?

Comment: You can use `format()` or cast it to a decimal or integer.  You'll have to add the `%` using `concat()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use calculated column names in the  `select` clause. And first multiplicate with 100 to avoid integer limitations

```
SUM(year = '15-16') * 100 / SUM(year = '14-15')  AS Diff
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because "Y1" and "Y2" doesnt exist on that context.

```
SELECT Site, Areateam, 
    SUM( IF( year = '15-16', 1, 0 ) ) "Y2", 
    SUM( IF( year = '14-15', 1, 0 ) ) "Y1",
    SUM( IF( year = '15-16', 1, 0 ) ) * 100 / 
    SUM( IF( year = '14-15', 1, 0 ) AS Diff
FROM CD2015_EmailIncidents
WHERE Areateam = 'Greater Manchester'
GROUP BY Site
```

Check here for rounding [ROUND OR TRUNC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11190668/format-number-to-2-decimal-places)

Comment: Wow, many thanks for your super quick reply!, I understand what you are saying your statement works!..thank you! however how can I control the NULL values and set decimal point to 2 places?


Site Areateam Y2 Y1 Diff
Acute Trust Greater Manchester 0 1 0.0000
Care Home Greater Manchester 3 22 13.6364
CD Store Room Greater Manchester 7 4 175.0000
College Greater Manchester 0 1 0.0000
Dental Practice Greater Manchester 1 0 NULL
Drug and Alcohol Service Greater Manchester 0 1 0.0000
GP Practice Greater Manchester 8 21 38.0952

Comment: Dont paste this kind of data in comment, Just update the question instead.

Comment: I include a link for the example for round or trunc. Take note the select answer only show TRUNC. You should check the one explaining both