# Column type for saving very different number of decimals

Tags: mysql, decimal

I need to store numbers like

```
21000
1.0002
0.00230235
12323235
0.2349523
```

This is sensordata so it is important to keep the exact value.
THere are many options.

My solution would be to multiply all values by 1 million, and store them as a bigint. Would that make sense?

Comment: if you don't need to treat those numbers as numbers in the db (e.g. no math/comparisons done on them), then storing as text would make most sense. the decimals won't be affected at all, because mysql won't mangle numbers-as-text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That makes sense but I'd recommend that you just use the `decimal` datatype: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html

If you were to multiply by million and if a dataset you receive has one more decimal than you'd expect, you'd end up multiplying that number by 10 million and all other numbers by 10. Instead, using the `decimal` datatype will give you 30 numbers to the right of the decimal.

> The declaration syntax for a DECIMAL column is DECIMAL(M,D). The
>   ranges of values for the arguments in MySQL 5.7 are as follows:
>
> M is the maximum number of digits (the precision). It has a range of 1
>   to 65.
>
> D is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point (the
>   scale). It has a range of 0 to 30 and must be no larger than M.

and

> The SQL standard requires that the precision of NUMERIC(M,D) be
>   exactly M digits. For DECIMAL(M,D), the standard requires a precision
>   of at least M digits but permits more. In MySQL, DECIMAL(M,D) and
>   NUMERIC(M,D) are the same, and both have a precision of exactly M
>   digits.
>
> For a full explanation of the internal format of DECIMAL values, see
>   the file strings/decimal.c in a MySQL source distribution. The format
>   is explained (with an example) in the decimal2bin() function.

To format your numbers, you could do formatting like this answer describes: [Format number to 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11190668/format-number-to-2-decimal-places)

**Example**

```
create table test (
  price decimal(40,20)
);

-- all the above insertions will succeed cleanly
insert into test values (1.5), (1.66), (1.777), (1.12345678901234567890);

-- notice we have 21 digits after decimal
-- MySQL will insert data with 20 decimal and add a warning regarding data truncation
insert into test values (1.123456789012345678901);
```

**Data**

```
select * from test

price
1.50000000000000000000
1.66000000000000000000
1.77700000000000000000
1.12345678901234567890
1.12345678901234567890

select cast(price as decimal(40,2)) from test

price
1.50
1.66
1.78
1.12
1.12
```

Comment: As I understand, for DECIMAL I need to set the exact amount of decimals, but those can vary? Or do I understand this wrong?

Comment: You can create a field called `price decimal (40,20)` and that will store 40 digits of which 20 will be to the right of the decimal point. That way, you can store 1.5, 1.66, 1.777, 1.12345678901234567890