# Data truncated for column when multiplying numbers

Tags: mysql

I am using the below query on the below data. However, when I do this I am getting the error "Data truncated for column 'strength' at row 1" for every column and row. I researched it a little, and as far as I can tell, most people are getting this error because they are trying to use text or char. I have never seen this warning before and I am getting the expected results, but with 4,700 warnings.

```
UPDATE userstats 
    SET strength = (strength * .999), 
        agility = (agility * .999), 
        guard = (guard * .999), 
        labour = (labour * .999), 
        IQ = (IQ * .999) 
WHERE gym_train_since_cron = 0
```

[image: Database columns]
[image: Database rows]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The `strength * .999` result will have more than 4 decimal digits and therefore it's truncating it, hence the error. That goes for all of this calculations actually.

Comment: @JonathonOgden I wondered if that was the case.. Is there anyway to round the resulting number to four decimal places to ensure my logs do not fill up with 4,700 warning everyday for the same thing?

Comment: @JonathonOgden  Found the answer to that on another stack overflow question.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11190668/format-number-to-2-decimal-places  Make your comment an answer and I will mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strength * .999` is resulting in a number with more than 4 decimal places. That goes for all of these calculations.

To avoid the warnings, you can either [ROUND](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round) or [TRUNCATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_truncate) the result of the calculation. For example: `SET strength = ROUND(strength * .999, 4)` or `SET strength = TRUNCATE(strength * .999, 4)`.

You may wonder what the difference between the two functions are; it's the rounding behavior. For `TRUNCATE` it will round a number towards 0, whereas `ROUND`, depending on the numeric data type (exact or approximate) which in your case is decimal (an exact type), the following occurs (taken from [Rounding Behavior](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-rounding.html)):

> For exact-value numbers, ROUND() uses the “round half up” rule: A value with a fractional part of .5 or greater is rounded up to the next integer if positive or down to the next integer if negative. (In other words, it is rounded away from zero.) A value with a fractional part less than .5 is rounded down to the next integer if positive or up to the next integer if negative.

To demonstrate, here's an example using the strength value for user 4898 from your sample data:

```
strength * .999 = 16331143.7521566 -- Over 4 decimal places, hence the warning
ROUND(strength * .999, 4) = 16331143.7522 -- Rounds up
TRUNCATE(strength * .999, 4) = 16331143.7521 -- Rounds down
```

Comment: Great explanation, sources, and examples. Thank you very much for your assistance!