# MySQL - Select unique values from a table

Tags: php, mysql, distinct

My MySQL table contains the following information,

```
ID  User            City            HomeLatitude      HomeLongitude
1   Egon Spengler   New York        19.123456         23.43546
2   Mac Taylor      New York        19.12343588       23.43546
3   Sarah Connor    New York        19.128376         34.35354
4   Jean-Luc Picard La Barre        11.345455         12.4356546
5   Ellen Ripley    Nostromo        32.76865          78.345435
```

From this table I need to query unique **HomeLatitude** values with first two decimal point because the first 3 location are almost same, so i need only the first row from the three rows..

I used the below given query,

```
SELECT DISTINCT HomeLatitude, City FROM user;
```

But that will return all the rows from the table. Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format number to 2 decimal places](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11190668/format-number-to-2-decimal-places)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[ROUND](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round) Function will give you the number of decimal places that you want to show.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ROUND(HomeLatitude,2), City FROM user GROUP BY ROUND(HomeLatitude,2);
```

Comment: But I need only the unique rows after rounding the HomeLatitude values.

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
   SELECT (DISTINCT ROUND(HomeLatitude, 1)) AS HomeLatitude, City FROM user;
```

Comment: I checked this, It will round HomeLatitude value to 2 decimal point, but the returned rows are not unique.

Comment: I changed the opening parenthesis. Otherwise you need the DISTINCT/ROUND as an inner query..

Comment: Sorry, its has some syntax error. I think its not possible to give parenthesis like that.

Comment: Ok, I think I mixed in some sqlite. My next suggestion would be to 'group by' but that already is the accepted answer. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

While using a solution that is based on rounding a latitude or longitude may give you results, also be prepared for unexpected results. It is also possible for two places to have the exact same latitude but different longitudes and vice verce.

If you are doing any kind of spatial analysis, you should invest in [mysql spatial extensions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-datatypes.html) and a function like [ST_WITHIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-relation-functions-object-shapes.html#function_st-within)

Second best option is to use the haversine formula or similar to find places that are close to each other.